# How to migrate/convert from SVN to Mercurial (hg) on windows

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial, migration, hgsvn

I'm looking for a tool to migrate a couple of SVN repositories to Mercurial, with history, labels and so on.

I'm using TortoiseHg (Windows x32), so ConvertExtensions are discarded. There's some info on how to do this process on a Linux box ([hgsvn](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/hgsvn)), but I don't have a Linux machine available.

Can I use those Python scripts on Windows? If so, what do I need to do it? Or, what other tools can I use to do this process?

Basically, how can I convert an SVN project to Mercurial?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

I just had to tackle this problem myself.  I have a windows XP machine with a separate windows server hosting [VisualSVN Server](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/).

I also have [TortoiseHG](https://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/) installed as well as the [CollabNet Subversion Command-Line Client](http://www.open.collab.net/downloads/subversion/).

**`<Enable Convert Extension w/ Tortoise Hg 2>`**

Many thanks to [bgever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/70182/bgever) for pointing out in the comments that with TortoiseHg 2.0, enabling the convert extension is easier than ever.  As he says

> With TortoiseHG 2.0 this has been made
>   much simpler: Start the TortoiseHG
>   Workbench from the Start menu. Select
>   File --> Settings. Select Extensions
>   from the list. Check the 'convert'
>   checkbox and click OK. That's it! No
>   need to try to generate the config
>   file anymore and search it in the file
>   system. – bgever Mar 11 at 7:56

**`</Enable Convert Extension w/ Tortoise Hg 2>`**

**`<Enable Convert Extension Manually>`**

To convert a repository from SVN to HG, I followed these steps:

1) Open C:\Program Files\TortoiseHg\Mercurial.ini

**EDIT**

FYI - Tortoise Hg has migrated this file to

- XP or older    - C:\Documents and Settings\USERNAME\Mercurial.ini
- Vista or later - C:\Users\USERNAME\Mercurial.ini

That file will be mostly empty and you'll just list what you'd like to override there.  If that's what you have, simple add these two lines to the very end of the file:

```
[extensions]
convert =
```

2) Search for the line that begins with

> [extensions]

3) Below it you'll see a list of keywords, commented out with a semicolon (;) on each line

4) Find the line that says

> ;convert =

and delete the semicolon so it reads

> convert =

**`</Enable Convert Extension Manually>`**

5) Open the command prompt and navigate to the directory that you'd like the new hg folder created in (the process will create a new folder called yoursvnreponame-hg in the directory that the command prompt is open to).

6) Use this command

> hg convert file:///y:/yoursvnreponame

I found that the convert tool can have problems with networked repositories, so I had to map a drive to it, but this worked just fine for me.

Comment: Selecting the answer for this question was difficult. evilbloodydemon was right when he commented in his answer to edit the config to enable the convert extension, but this answer is more clear and precise

Comment: I just wanted to mention that i tested this without the SVN command line client and it worked as well.  You don't even need an SVN server functioning to do this, just access to the repository file path.

Comment: This worked well for me with Mercurial V1.4.3. A 1-year-old svn repository converted very quickly with the full history intact. Many thanks!

Comment: Thanks, especially for the detailed instructions on which config file to edit.  For reference, this also works when converting from an svn repo served over svn://

Comment: Just to add - the ini file is not created on a default TortoiseHG installation. You need to apply/save some settings first or start with a blank file if you know what you doing.

Comment: With TortoiseHG 2.0 this has been made much simpler: Start the TortoiseHG Workbench from the Start menu. Select File --> Settings. Select Extensions from the list. Check the 'convert' checkbox and click OK. That's it! No need to try to generate the config file anymore and search it in the file system.

Comment: Just a minor suggestion. If you add the debug and traceback options to the convert command in step 6, you will get a lot more details when converting a repository, e.g. "hg convert --debug --traceback file://y:/yoursvnreponame".

I was wondering why the converting process seemed to hang at first, but with the debug and traceback options you can actually see what's going on at all times.

Comment: Beware that this doesn't work anymore since THG version 3.4: https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/wiki/ReleaseNotes#!tortoisehg-34 https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issues/4174/svn-no-compatible-bindings-available-in

Answer (score 8):

1. startup svn server on localhost
2. hg convert svn://localhost/your_repo
3. done, because svn bindings needed only for file:// protocol

Comment: Nopes, neither mercurial binaries for win32 or TortoiseHg comes with convert extensions, so "hg convert" is not even a valid command on win32.

Comment: I tried using svn:// instead of file:// but it keeps asking for Python bindings

Comment: Using svn:// instead of file:// worked for me without the Python bindings. To start the svn server the command is: svnserve -r <path to repo root> -d

Answer (score 7):

Mercurial has a [built-in conversion extension for this](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/RepositoryConversion#Subversion).

Comment: I know, It's the first thing i stumbled upon, but quoting: "Note that you can't do this with the Win32 Mercurial binaries -- there's no way to install the Subversion bindings into its built-in Python library"
I'm using TortoiseHg ...

Comment: Use a Linux live CD or a virtual machine?

Comment: This is absolutely correct answer. I have done this using hg convert extension only (http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/wiki/WorkingWithSubversion#With_Convert_extension) and using the file protocol for SVN repository without pysvn extension:
hg convert file:///X:/HOME/REPOS/mysvnrep newhgrep

Answer (score 5):

To convert an SVN Repo to an HG Repo AND copy it to a different server, you will need a few things.

1. TortoiseHG installed. (Check to see what version is currently being used)
2. Python Installed. (Check to see what version is currently being used)
3. The Python Modules (you can find them http://pysvn.tigris.org/project_downloads.html)
4. You will need to add the `convert` extension to Tortoise. Start the TortoiseHG Workbench from the Start menu. Select `File -> Settings`. Select `Extensions` from the list. Check the `convert` checkbox and click OK.

First the conversion…

1. It is best to map the Folder that the current SVN Repo is in to the computer you are working on. (i.e. `\\server\folder`  Do not map the SVN Repo folder itself. Map the folder just above it) Give the mapped drive a letter, like `Y:\`
2. Open a command Prompt and type:  `CD /D Y:\`
3. At the `Y:\` prompt type:  `hg convert y:/RepoName`   (use the name of the current Repo)  Be careful of the forward and back slashes. The one in the command is a forward slash. Also, if the name has spaces, put the name in quotations. (i.e. `Y:/"My Repo folder"`)
4. Now it should be running and will create another folder alongside the old one. And an hg folder should be inside. IT WILL NOT BE INITIATED, AND DO NOT INITIATE!
5. The conversion is complete.

Second the cloning…

1. Open TortoiseHG Workbench. Go to `File -> Clone Repository`
2. Source: Enter the full path of the converted repo.
3. Destination: Enter the full path of where you want the repo cloned. It is not necessary to create a folder at the new destination as the cloning process will create it and initialize it.
4. Add the permissions to the new cloned folder.
5. You’re done!!!

Comment: Hi, is it possible to explain why you should not `init` the first repository?

Answer (score 3):

Nobody still does not mention [hgsubversion](https://bitbucket.org/durin42/hgsubversion) ([Extension Wiki](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/HgSubversion)), which can do it without almost any headache (excluding rare cases and specific tree).

Just add extension, enable it and `hg clone SVN_REPO` to local mercurial repo

Answer (score 1):

This is in the [TortoiseHg FAQ](http://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/stable/wiki/FAQ#how-can-i-convert-a-subversion-repository-to-mercurial):

> #### How can I convert a subversion repository to Mercurial?
>
> You must install svn-win32-1.4.6 command line tools, then add them to your path. Then you must enable the convert extension. At this point, you should be able to use the '`hg convert`' command to do the conversion. Please direct problems/questions about the convert extension to the Mercurial mailing list or `#mercurial` on `irc.freenode.net`.

So it is apparently possible -- I'm using Linux so I haven't tried myself.

Answer (score 0):

I just converted a remote SVN repo with HTTP auth to a Mercurial repo, and let me tell you, there's not a lot of documentation on how to do this. I had to download the Mercurial source and install it stand-alone, using the source package, that way the SVN bindings will work the right way.

I installed it like:

```
python setup.py install
```

Which worked just fine on my Server 2003 box. I can now convert an SVN repo the correct way, by doing something like this:

```
python c:\python26\scripts\hg convert <remote repo>
```

The documentation for ConvertExtension on the Mercurial site isn't terribly clear, but it does say this:

> There's no way to install the
>   Subversion bindings into [Mercurial's] built-in
>   Python library. So you'll need to use
>   a Mercurial installed on top of a
>   stand-alone Python

So now I just use the stand-alone version for converting, and TortoiseHg for actual VCS work.

Answer (score 0):

better late than never ...

Two answers for the price of one ...

1. If it is a public, open-source repo you could just use http://svn2github.com/add/ which took about half an hour to clone that repo to GitHib and then just pull that into Hg.
2. The advantage of using **`hg convert`** is that is can be resumed. Converting SVN to Hg can take **days**. If you stop this it will resume from where it left off.

Below is a batch file I wrote because Codeplex SVNbridge rubbish. The repo in this example did take a couple of days to fetch the whole history (I'm in Australia so the latency may have been a factor). I'd like to think it gave a TFS server somewhere a good beating.

This batch file can be run at any time to pull updates from the SVN source if they happen to be the only ones left on earth actually still using SVN. I haven't tested it so see what happens if you do this so if I were you I'd abandon the original branch if you're going to edit the repo.

The `robocopy shamap` stuff is to maintain the SVN history if you clone the Hg repo, shamap is ephemeral - check the batch file & shamap in (I'd do that on a new branch).

the batch...

```
@echo off
mode con:cols=100 lines=800

:: Change the SVN remote name here
::
set remote=https://cinch.svn.codeplex.com/svn
::

title Fetching SVN from %remote%. This could take...DAYS
echo .
echo Fetching SVN checkins from %remote%
echo .
echo Dependencies: Tortoise Hg and hg.exe in the Path would be ideal.
echo using hg convert
echo .
echo First, I will make a backup of shamap in the hg repo folder.
echo If shamap in .hg\ is newer then it will be copied to the repo.
echo You should commit it so hg clones of this repo work with this.
echo Commit this .BeeyATch file as well.
echo shamap keeps track of what has been fetched from SVN.
echo ok, that ends the educational part of this script...
echo Now I will fetch SVN changes from
echo %remote%
echo ...
echo ...(this could take quite some time)...
echo ...DAYS...yes...DAYS
echo ...especially if it's fecking Codeplex SVN...
echo .
echo If this craps out just run it again - it will resume from where it left off. 
echo and fetch the rest...eventually
echo .
echo Control C to abort or any other key to start:
echo .

pause

echo .
:: http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension <== see for details of shamap
:: copy the shamap from the original convert into the .hg folder unless it is already there & newer
:: don't panic if shamap is much bigger than the original - diff it to see why
robocopy .\ .\.hg\ shamap /XO 
robocopy .\.hg\ .\ shamap /XO 
echo .

hg convert --verbose --debug %remote% "%CD%"
echo .
echo .
echo Finished fetching from %remote%
title Finished fetching from %remote%
echo Any  key to Exit
echo .
pause

exit
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the [`convert` extension](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConvertExtension) of Mercurial:

1. Enable convert extention; add `convert=` to the `[extensions]` section of .hgrc like this:

   > [extensions]
   >   convert=
2. *Linux needs additional python bindings: `sudo apt-get install python-subversion`*
3. Execute `hg convert` command

   - See `hg convert -h` for help
   - Example: `hg convert http://[svnserver]/[Project] --source-type svn [DestinationDir]` *(see note 2)*
4. Push to newly created Mercurial repository: `hg push https://[mercurialserver]/[Project]`

**note**: you can even repeat the hg convert command to include new changes made in the svn repository after the previous convert.

**note 2**: When hg convert doesn't work using `http://` or `svn://` you could first checkout the Subversion repository (or update an existing one) and convert using the local checkout; example: `hg convert [DirectoryOfLocalCheckout] --source-type svn [DestinationDir]`