# hg : how to convert a single subversion branch

Tags: svn, version-control, mercurial

I have a subversion repository, where each branch is a separate project. I would like to change this architecture, and to gradually move to mercurial. How can I convert a single branch of a subversion repo into an hg repository.

hg version : 1.01

Comment: 1.01? (from http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/WhatsNew#Version_1.0.1_-_2008-05-22 may 2008?). That may be a bit old for that kind of operation, although convert was *just* enhanced in this version!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the [Convert Extension](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ConvertExtension) (see also this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/850213/how-to-migrate-convert-from-svn-to-mercurial-hg-on-windows)), and convert directly the project/branch you need

```
hg convert http://url/to/svn/myproject/mybranch
```

Comment: +1 , The only time this gets strange  is when the trunk happened to move around in the SVN repo. If that happens, you end up with multiple heads.

Comment: Thank you, I though I would have to mess with a filemap file.